# Listener to notify the completion of a series of events(starting simultaneous services)

Tags: java, android

I have three classes from which I start three services. These three services will be started simultaneously.

I have callback methods in each of these service class to know whether that particular service has been started.

There is no order in which what service out of these three would get started first, though they are started simultaneously.

Can someone please let me know the best approach to use in order that I am notified at the start of last service?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
public class CounterAndNotifier
{
    private int counter = 0;
    private int count;
    private Runnable runnable;

    public CounterAndNotifier(int count, Runnable runnable)
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    public synchronized void incrementCounter()
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == count) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Create a class that takes a `Runnable` which should be notified once all the three services start.
2. This class maintains a counter and a `synchronized` method to increment the counter.
3. The method to increment the counter will call the `Runnable.run()` once the count reaches `3`.
4. Create an object of this class and pass it to the three services to call the `incrementCounter()` method once the service is complete up and running.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any sample examples online or reference links would be of great help

Comment: @user1400538, updated my response with a simple CounterAndNotifier that does what I described below it.

Comment: sorry, from which class I should call CounterAndNotifier constructor from?

Comment: The main class that starts the services and also contains the method that should be called by once all the services start.

Comment: ok, I implements the Runnable in main class and call the constructor as `CounterAndNotifier cn = new CounterAndNotifier(0, this)` and inside the callbacks of each of the 3 service classes where I get the service started event notification, I call incrementCounter . Correct me if I am wrong. I will try this tomorrow and accept your answer if this resolves my query. thx

Comment: Everything sounds right except the value in the constructor, it should be number of services (3 in your case) and not 0.